# Converting American to Canadian

Tags: arithmetic, dimensional-analysis

Paid \$1012 American for a group of items, which worked out to \$1248.99 Canadian. How do I calculate the conversion rate so I can figure out the total cost Canadian of each item?

Comment: So...what is the question exactly?

Comment: Do I have to divide $1248.99 by $1012? This seems easy I know by for some reason it has me stumped

Comment: Which of the numbers is in Canadian dollars?  Your question has both of them American.

Comment: for instance 1 item cost $158 American. All I have for information is I paid $1248.99 Canadian for the total bill of $1012 American. So I need to figure out what the exact exchange based on that math would be.

Comment: If you get confused and can’t figure out whether the conversion factor is $\dfrac{1248.99}{1012}$ or $\dfrac{1012}{1248.99}$ — it’s definitely one or the other! — take a moment to think about which currency is more valuable. In your example, Canadian dollars are less valuable, so it should take more of them to purchase any individual item.

Answer (score 3):

$\require{cancel}$Since the currencies are denominated using the same symbol, \$, I'll use the [ISO 4217 currency codes](http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php) USD and CAD.

We know from your receipt and bank statement (or whatever) that
$$1012 \text{ USD} = 1248.99 \text{ CAD}.$$

To convert from USD to CAD, we must multiply an amount by the conversion factor in CAD/USD, which is
$$\frac{1248.99 \text{ CAD}}{1012 \text{ USD}} \approx 1.234 \text{ CAD/USD},$$
which we can also write as $$\frac{1.234 \text{ CAD}}{1 \text{ USD}}.$$

So, for example, converting the cost of the 158.00 USD item mentioned in the comments gives that in CAD, it cost
$$158.00 \text{ }\cancel{\text{USD}} \cdot \frac{1.234 \text{ CAD}}{1 \text{ }\cancel{\text{USD}}} = (158.00 \cdot 1.234) \text{ CAD} \approx 195.00 \text{ CAD}.$$

Comment: Is there a way to strike through text (e.g., to emphasize cancellation) in MathJax?

Comment: Use \require{cancel} \cancel{some math} in math mode.

Comment: This is the right way to look at things, but I would have taken it one step further: from the equation 
$1012$USD = $1248.99$CAD, I would have solved for either “USD” or “CAD”, depending on which way you were going. You would get, for instance USD$=1.234$CAD, so that any time you saw a price in US dollars, you make the substitution (for “\$”) and get an answer in Canadian dollars.

Comment: Cheers, @GabrielH!

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is linear, so if \$1012 American is worth \$1248.99, each American dollar is worth $\dfrac{1248.99}{1012}= 1.23418$ Canadian.  Multiply any American dolar amount by that and you get the equivalent amount in Canadian dollars.